# disabling "user" pdb.set_trace()s under nose

Tags: python, nose

Note:  this is kinda the opposite of `nosetests --pdb ...`

I typically use this pattern in my unit tests.

```
try:
    assert something
except Exception, e:
    if flag_pdb_enabled:  pdb.set_trace()
    raise
```

This way, as I run individual tests, I can drop into the debugger as soon as I get an exception.

Now, most of the time I am careful to guard the `pdb.set_trace()` with the conditional.  But sometimes I forget and I have:

```
try:
    assert something
except Exception, e:
    pdb.set_trace()
    raise
```

Problem is, under `nosetests` the tests just halt and I get no indication that the debugger is underway.  I have to then go on a hunt for those stray unguarded pdb triggers.

Yes, I know this might not be best QA practices, but this system works well except for the occasional unexpected halting.

Is there a way to either:

- patch the basic pdb.set_trace so that it does nothing under nosetests?
- alternative:  drop down into nosetests's own debugger, just as you get from `nosetests --pdb`?

My tests are aware whether they're under `nosetests` or not, through the std `if __name__ == "__main__":`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `nosetests -s` (or `--nocapture`) then you'll get an actual `pdb` prompt rather than a hang.  This only helps if you're running the tests interactively, of course, but it's probably still an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

It's a messy solution but you could use unittest.mock

something like

```
import unittest.mock
with mock.patch('pdb.set_trace') as mock:
  #run tests
```

Comment: txs, your idea pointed me to an alternative solution.  I am not totally sure it will not foul up `nosetests --pdb`'s own debugging, but I rarely use that.

Answer (score 0):

The mocking idea is good, but I sometimes find mock a bit daunting and struggle with getting at the mock target early enough to patch it.   But I really don't need anything sophisticated, just a do-nothing behavior.

This is what I did:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...stuff to run tests...
else:
    #existing nosetests branch

    def do_nothing(*args, **kwds):
        logger.warning("fake pdb.set_trace()")
        return
    pdb.set_trace = do_nothing

    ...stuff to run tests...
```

It worked well enough. My intentional `pdb.set_trace` was totally ignored.

Doesn't even interfere with `nosetests --pdb` which must be its own function reference:  my "user pdb" printed out fake and nosetests's debugger triggered on other exceptions.

This is on Python 2.7's nosetests btw.